# jenkins server not taking artifactory server details

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, devops, artifactory, jfrog-container-registry

My jenkins and jfrog artifactory both are running as kubernetes containers. I am trying to integrate jenkins with artifactory. I have installed artifactory pluggin as well. while testing connection I'm getting error.

```
docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-oss(docker-image)

NAME              TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                         AGE
artifactory-oss   NodePort    172.30.155.24   <none>        8086:30965/TCP,8082:30656/TCP   4h

artifactory url: http://<kubernetes-node-ip:30656/ui(this is the url for my artifactory, entered the same in jenkins congigure system section)
```

when I test connection i'm getting this error

```
Error occurred while requesting version information: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
at [Source: (org.apache.http.client.entity.LazyDecompressingInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]
```

Comment: Have you tested the communication between your pods and service? How did you tested? What have you tried so far and which results you got?

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: Try switching `/ui` to `/artifactory`.

The Artifactory's URL should not end with `/ui`. Requests to `/ui` would return a HTTP page. I guess this is where the `<` came from.

Connection to Artifactory should be made by the API url, i.e https://[base-url]/artifactory.

Comment: Thanks,  I changed custome base url to /artifactoty..it  worked